# How to set MuiButton text and active color

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm creating a Material-UI theme with:

```
export const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#7ab800',
      dark: '#34b233',
    },
  })
```

which gives me a Button with a default of the `main` color and the active background is the `dark` green:

[image]

However I want the text to be white. If I define `contrastText` in the `primary` property with:

```
export const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#7ab800',
      dark: '#34b233',
      contrastText: 'white',
    },
  })
```

on being active, the active background is now lighter than the `main`...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "active" background you are referring to is caused by the Button's `TouchRipple` effect. You can find the styling for this in the [`TouchRipple` source code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/ButtonBase/TouchRipple.js):

```
  /* Styles applied to the internal `Ripple` components `child` class. */
  child: {
    opacity: 1,
    display: 'block',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    borderRadius: '50%',
    backgroundColor: 'currentColor',
  }
```

Notice that the `backgroundColor` of the ripple is 'currentColor'. So when the text color is black, the ripple's background color is black and when the text color is white the ripple's background color is white. This helps ensure that the ripple causes a visible effect on the button -- a black ripple on a button with a black background wouldn't show up, but the current color should always be a contrast to the background.

Like nearly all styles in Material-UI, you can of course customize this once you know how. In the sample code below you can see how to override this in the theme using `overrides: { MuiTouchRipple: {...} }` or on a single button using `TouchRippleProps` passing in the `child` class within the `classes` prop.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  createMuiTheme,
  MuiThemeProvider,
  withStyles
} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
const theme1 = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#7ab800",
      dark: "#34b233"
    }
  }
});
console.log(theme1);
const theme2 = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#7ab800",
      dark: "#34b233",
      contrastText: "white"
    }
  }
});
const theme3 = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#7ab800",
      dark: "#34b233",
      contrastText: "white"
    }
  },
  overrides: {
    MuiTouchRipple: {
      child: {
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)"
      }
    }
  }
});
const styles = {
  child: {
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)"
  }
};

function App({ classes }) {
  return (
    <>
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme1}>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
          Theme 1
        </Button>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
      <br />
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme2}>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
          Theme 2
        </Button>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" disableRipple>
          Theme 2 No Ripple
        </Button>
        <Button
          TouchRippleProps={{ classes: classes }}
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
        >
          Theme 2 button-specific Ripple Override
        </Button>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
      <br />
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme3}>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
          Theme 3 - theme-wide Ripple Override
        </Button>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    </>
  );
}
const StyledApp = withStyles(styles)(App);
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<StyledApp />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit 617pw32323]