# Change Ripple Color on click of Material UI <Button />

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

This is my `<MyButton />` Component

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const styles = theme => ({
  button: {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "red"
    },
  },
});

function MyButton(props) {

  return (
    <Button
      className={props.classes.button} >
      {props.text}
    </Button>
  );
}

export default withStyles(styles)(MyButton);
```

Currently, there is the default click effect on the button, brightening/lightening it up on click (see here: https://material-ui.com/demos/buttons/). However, I want the color of the "ripple" to be `blue` when the button is clicked.

I tried

```
"&:click": {
    backgroundColor: "blue"
},
```

and

```
"&:active": {
    backgroundColor: "blue"
},
```

No luck though. How do I change the color of the ripple when the button is clicked?

Comment: check this https://material-ui.com/api/touch-ripple/#touchripple-api

Comment: @sarvonks not sure how to apply this to the `<MyButton />` component.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's an example showing how to modify the button ripple for v4 (v5 example further down):

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const styles = theme => ({
  button: {
    backgroundColor: "green",
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "red"
    }
  },
  child: {
    backgroundColor: "blue"
  },
  rippleVisible: {
    opacity: 0.5,
    animation: `$enter 550ms ${theme.transitions.easing.easeInOut}`
  },
  "@keyframes enter": {
    "0%": {
      transform: "scale(0)",
      opacity: 0.1
    },
    "100%": {
      transform: "scale(1)",
      opacity: 0.5
    }
  }
});

function MyButton({ classes, ...other }) {
  const { button: buttonClass, ...rippleClasses } = classes;
  return (
    <Button
      TouchRippleProps={{ classes: rippleClasses }}
      className={buttonClass}
      {...other}
    />
  );
}

export default withStyles(styles)(MyButton);
```

[image: Edit button ripple]

The default opacity of the ripple is 0.3. In the example I have increased this to 0.5 to make it easier to verify that the ripple is blue. Since the button background is red (due to the hover styling), the result is purple. You'll get a different overall effect if you move to the button via the keyboard since the blue will be layered on top of the button's green background.

You'll find some additional background in my answer here: [How to set MuiButton text and active color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54661163/how-to-set-muibutton-text-and-active-color/54662218#54662218)

The main resource for the styling of the ripple is its source code: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.10.2/packages/material-ui/src/ButtonBase/TouchRipple.js

JSS keyframes documentation: https://cssinjs.org/jss-syntax/?v=v10.3.0#keyframes-animation

---

Here's a similar example for MUI v5:

```
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { keyframes } from "@emotion/react";

const enterKeyframe = keyframes`
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
`;
const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  background-color: green;
  &:hover {
    background-color: red;
  }
  && .MuiTouchRipple-child {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  && .MuiTouchRipple-rippleVisible {
    opacity: 0.5;
    animation-name: ${enterKeyframe};
    animation-duration: 550ms;
    animation-timing-function: ${({ theme }) =>
      theme.transitions.easing.easeInOut};
  }
`;
export default StyledButton;
```

[image: Edit button ripple]

v5 TouchRipple source code: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.4.0/packages/mui-material/src/ButtonBase/TouchRipple.js#L92

Emotion keyframes documentation: https://emotion.sh/docs/keyframes

Answer demonstrating use of keyframes: [How to apply custom animation effect @keyframes in MUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58948890/how-to-apply-custom-animation-effect-keyframes-in-materialui-using-makestyles/58958349#58958349)

Answer (score 4):

Here is the hack for **Material-UI 4.9.10**

Add a class to button and then add the below code to given class

```
 Btn:{
    "& .MuiTouchRipple-root span":{
      backgroundColor: 'red!important',
      opacity: .3,
    },
},
```

Comment: FYI -- I've updated my answer (originally written for v3) to work for v4 (without resorting to "!important").

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS - can be tricky to identify the class for the MUI component at times, but for our usage of the `<ListItem>` element which is rendered like a button:

```
.MuiListItem-button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(23, 93, 131, 0.12) !important;
}
.MuiTouchRipple-rippleVisible {
  color: #005d83 !important;
}
```

Note: we use a dark blue and customized the `background-color` attribute with some opacity.

Answer (score 0):

I've adapted the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61245118/2891356) answer to work with [styled components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-components) and [emotion/styled](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@emotion/styled).

```
const ButtonStyledWithSC = styledSC(Button)`
  && {
    background-color: magenta;
    width: 10rem;
    height: 3rem;
    margin: 10px;

    &:hover {
      background-color: white;
    }

    > .MuiTouchRipple-root span {
      background-color: cyan;
    }
  }
`;
```

[image: heuristic-feistel-0znpi]