# MUI 5 - keyframe animation using styled API not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to animate a button when hovered using `styled` from MUI 5 - but it is not working. I tried to find inspiration from:

- [How to apply custom animation effect @keyframes in MaterialUI using makestyles()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58948890/how-to-apply-custom-animation-effect-keyframes-in-materialui-using-makestyles)
- https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/24851

.. with no luck.

Try and have a look and tell what *I* cannot see:

```js
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { keyframes } from "@emotion/react";

const getAnimation = () => keyframes`
    0 %  { transform: translate(1px, 1px)   rotate(0deg)    },
    10%  { transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);  },
    20%  { transform: translate(-3px, 0px)  rotate(1deg);   },
    30%  { transform: translate(3px, 2px)   rotate(0deg);   },
    40%  { transform: translate(1px, -1px)  rotate(1deg);   },
    50%  { transform: translate(-1px, 2px)  rotate(-1deg);  },
    60%  { transform: translate(-3px, 1px)  rotate(0deg);   },
    70%  { transform: translate(3px, 1px)   rotate(-1deg);  },
    80%  { transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);   },
    90%  { transform: translate(1px, 2px)   rotate(0deg);   },
    100% { transform: translate(1px, -2px)  rotate(-1deg);  }
`;

const StyledButton = styled((props) => {
  const { ...other } = props;
  return <Button {...other} />;
})(({ theme }) => ({
  ":hover": {
    animation: `${getAnimation} shake infinite`
  },
  backgroundColor: "#2699FB",
  color: "#FFFFFF"
}));

const App = () => {
  return (
    <StyledButton variant="contained">
              My button
    </StyledButton>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emotion's [`keyframe`](https://emotion.sh/docs/keyframes) is a [tag function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates). It accepts a template string as the first argument and returns the keyframe data. What you defined in your code is a function that just returns another function without doing anything:

```
const getAnimation = () => keyframes`
    0 %  { transform: translate(1px, 1px)   rotate(0deg)    },
    ...
    100% { transform: translate(1px, -2px)  rotate(-1deg);  }
`;
```

You're supposed to change the code to this:

```
const myKeyframe = keyframes`
    0 %  { transform: translate(1px, 1px)   rotate(0deg)    },
    ...
    100% { transform: translate(1px, -2px)  rotate(-1deg);  }
`;
```

### Usage

```
const StyledButton = styled((props) => <Button {...props} />)(({ theme }) => ({
  ":hover": {
    backgroundColor: "#2699FB",
    // I also fixed the animation sub-property order of yours
    // See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations#configuring_the_animation
    animation: `${myKeyframe} 1s infinite ease`
  },
  backgroundColor: "#2699FB",
  color: "#FFFFFF"
}));
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 2):

This s eem to work for me

1. Inside sx prop

> ```
> <Box
>   sx={{
>     animationName: "move",  
>     "@keyframes move": {
>        "0%": {
>          opacity: 0,
>        },
>        "50%": {
>          opacity: 1,
>        },
>        "100%": {
>          opacity: 0,
>         },
>     },          
>   }}
> >
>  Content
> </Box>
> ```

or

2)

```
import { keyframes } from "@mui/system";
```

...

```
const shake = keyframes`
  25% { transform: translateX(-1px); }    
  75% { transform: translateX(1px); }
`;
```

...

```
<Box
  sx={{
    animation: `${shake} .5s linear infinite;`,
    width: "75px",
    height: "75px",
  }}
>
...
</Box>
```