# Add shake animation when the character limit react 100

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a component that has a limitation, character limit that if it the user reach the limit the component will shake, thats the expected result, but in my current code nothing happen.

```
   const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
     shake:{
       animation: 'description 0.5s',
       animationIterationCount: '1',
     },
    '@keyframes description':{
       '0%': { transform: 'translate(0)' },
       '15%': { transform: 'translate(-4px, 0)' },
       '30%': { transform: 'translate(6px, 0)' },
       '45%': { transform: 'translate(-4px, 0)' },
       '60%': { transform: 'translate(6px, 0)' },
       '100%': { transform: 'translate(0)' },
      },
   }));
   const StudentAdd = ({ setOpenAlertStudent }) => {
     const classes = useStyles();
     const CHARACTER_LIMIT = 100;
     const [isShake, setShake] = useState(false)

     const onHandleChangeInputDescription = (field, value) => {
        if(value.length === 100){
          setShake(true)
     }
   ......
    <TextArea
      label="Description (optional)"
      inputProps={{
        maxLength: CHARACTER_LIMIT,
      }}
      values={getStringDescription.name}
      onChange={(value) =>
        onHandleChangeInputDescription('description', value)
      }
      helperText={`${getStringDescription.length}/${CHARACTER_LIMIT}`}
      className={
        isShake
          ? classes.shake
          : null
      }
      id="description"
      //id={isShake === true ? classes.shake : 'description'}
    />
  ......
```

this is the sample code on codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-banach-o6sc1j?file=/src/App.js:1081-1089

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  shake: {
    animation: "$description 15s",
    animationIterationCount: "1"
  },
  "@keyframes description": {
    "0%": { opacity: 0, transform: "translateY(0)" },
    "15%": { transform: "translateY(-4px, 0)" },
    "30%": { transform: "translateY(6px, 0)" },
    "45%": { transform: "translateY(-4px, 0)" },
    "60%": { transform: "translateY(6px, 0)" },
    "100%": { opacity: 1, transform: "translateY(0)" }
  }
}));
export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  console.log(classes.shake);
  const CHARACTER_LIMIT = 100;
  const [isShake, setShake] = useState(false);
  const [getStringDescription, setStringDescription] = useState({
    length: 0,
    value: ""
  });
  const onHandleChangeInputDescription = (field, value) => {
    if (value.target.value.length === 100) {
      setShake(true);
    }
    setStringDescription({
      length: value.target.value.length,
      value: value.target.value
    });
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextField
        label="Description"
        inputProps={{
          maxLength: CHARACTER_LIMIT
        }}
        values={getStringDescription.name}
        onChange={(value) =>
          onHandleChangeInputDescription("description", value)
        }
        helperText={`${getStringDescription.length}/${CHARACTER_LIMIT}`}
        sx={{
          "& .MuiInputBase-input.MuiInputBase-inputMultiline": {
            height: "100px !important"
          },
          "& .MuiTextField-root > .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
            padding: "8.5px 14px"
          }
        }}
        id="description"
        className={isShake ? classes.shake : null}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

1. your shaking animation code is not working, make changes in the keyframes for desired animation.
2. upon 100 character the animation class will be added. but once added you may need to remove the class, inorder to display the animation once again if the character is 100.

reference: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58948890/how-to-apply-custom-animation-effect-keyframes-in-mui[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58948890/how-to-apply-custom-animation-effect-keyframes-in-mui%5B1%5D)